# What is the preferred syntax for a stateless react function? Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Method 1:

```
const BasicProfileInfo = (props: BasicProfileInfoProps) => {
    return (
            <MainContainer>
              {....}
            </MainContainer>
    )
}
```

Method 2:

```
function BasicProfileInfo(props: BasicProfileInfoProps){
    return (
            <MainContainer>
              {....}
            </MainContainer>
    )
}
```

Project Environment:

- babel-eslint: 8.0.2
- babel-plugin-transform-class-properties: 6.24.1
- babel-preset-es2015: 6.24.1
- babel-preset-react-native: 4.0.0
- react: 16.0.0
- react-native: 0.48.4
- mobx: 3.3.1
- mobx-react: 4.3.3

Comment: Unless you use `this` in the function (which would be a strange choice to do in a *stateless* component), they're functionally equivalent. Use whichever one looks nicest to you.

Answer (score 3):

Arrow function can be shortened to implied return:

```
const BasicProfileInfo = (props: BasicProfileInfoProps) => (
    <MainContainer>
      {....}
    </MainContainer>
);
```

But it has a bit more footprint in ES5 output than regular function declaration, because an arrow is transpiled to regular function any way:

```
var BasicProfileInfo = function BasicProfileInfo(props) { return ... }
```

This is the only difference between them as stateless components. Arrow functions don't have their own `this` and `arguments`, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of using the 'arrow function' notation is that [arrow functions don't have their own `this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), which is useful if you want to preserve `this` from an outer function definition.

But, if your component is stateless, this doesn't matter, so it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: "which is useful if you want to preserve this from an outer function definition." which is totally useless w/ stateless components.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes - I've added this to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

React components will use the function name as the [displayName](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname) in debug messages and the developers console. The default displayName is `Component`, which is much less useful. This alone I think is enough to always prefer explicitly named functions (Method 2).

EDIT: As noted below, either of OP's methods will result in the displayName being populated correctly. The only situation that it will not is when exporting truly anonymous functions like: `export default () => {}`. So the other answers here are more relevant.

Comment: Arrow functions have names: `const myFunc = () => {}; console.log(myFunc.name); // logs "myFunc"` So I think your reasoning here is mistaken.

Comment: Hey you're right! It appears that arrow functions automatically use the name of the variable they are assigned to. So that means my answer is only relevant when exporting truly anonymous functions like: `export default () => {}`, which should be avoided IMO.